# Upload images to a text field with PHP and other HTML5 technologies

Tags: php, html, contenteditable

Imagine if I could drag and drop images to this text field I'm writing in. Well for my site, I'd like to give users that ability to do it and have it save to the database. Now when I save it to the database, I'd like the image locations of the text field to be replaced with probably the file name, and just have the file name be replaced by the image when it displays the "blog" post.

I don't know if anyone here has used deviantArt's Stash writer, but I'm going for something similar with a PHP solution (and hopefully little JS since my knowledge on that is narrow).

If there is already an easy class/script to do this, please tell me! I'm not looking for a CMS since I'm designing a service of my own to do this. I'm just think that this would bolster the user experience as well as solve the problem of allowing users to upload pictures (that's why I'm not looking for a gallery solution because I know how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Try this somewhat match your needs .
http://www.uploadify.com/about/

Comment: This is just for the image upload. Now I need the ability to add it to a text area of some sort (doesn't have to be a text area)